# Output doesn't match input

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a macro that's meant to created a lump of CSS & HTML from a set of values in each sheet of a spreadsheet.
It's a little untidy as I created the function to write it from one sheet first as a proof of concept, and then updated it.
It doesn't throw any obvious errors, but the output varies, sometimes it shows the same thing both times, and then depending on where I've got debug MsgBoxs or watches in VBA seems to alter the output.

Any ideas what on earth i'm doing wrong?

[image: SHeet 1]
[image: Sheet 2]

```
Sub createCode()

Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set myWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

For Each mySheet In myWorkbook.Worksheets

    Dim bannerCount As Integer
    Dim BannerCollection() As Banner
    Dim r As Range
    Dim lastRow, lastCol
    Dim allCells As Range
    bannerCount = 0
    lastCol = mySheet.Range("a2").End(xlToRight).Column
    lastRow = mySheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown).Row
    Set allCells = mySheet.Range("a2", mySheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
'    MsgBox (mySheet.Name)
'    MsgBox ("lastRow:" & lastRow & "lastCol:" & lastCol)
    ReDim BannerCollection(allCells.Rows.Count)

    For Each r In allCells.Rows
        Dim thisBanner As Banner
        thisBanner.imagePath = ""
        thisBanner.retImagePath = ""
        thisBanner.bannerTitle = ""
        thisBanner.urlPath = ""
        bannerCount = bannerCount + 1
'        MsgBox (bannerCount)
        thisBanner.imagePath = Cells(r.Row, 2).Value
        thisBanner.retImagePath = Cells(r.Row, 3).Value
        thisBanner.bannerTitle = Cells(r.Row, 4).Value
        thisBanner.urlPath = Cells(r.Row, 5).Value
        'MsgBox (Cells(r.Row, 2).Value)
        'MsgBox (Cells(r.Row, 3).Value)
        'MsgBox (Cells(r.Row, 4).Value)
        'MsgBox (Cells(r.Row, 5).Value)
        BannerCollection(bannerCount - 1) = thisBanner
    Next r

    Dim i As Variant
    Dim retinaCSS, imgCSS, firstBannerCode, otherBannersCode, bannerTracking As String
    retinaCSS = ""
    imgCSS = ""
    firstBannerCode = ""
    otherBannersCode = ""
    bannerTracking = ""


    For i = 0 To bannerCount - 1
        bannerTracking = BannerCollection(i).bannerTitle
        bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, " ", "+")
        bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "&", "And")
        bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "%", "PC")
        bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "!", "")
        bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "Â£", "")
        bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, ",", "")
        bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "'", "")
        bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "#", "")
        bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, ".", "")
        retinaCSS = retinaCSS & "#sliderTarget .banner-" & i + 1 & "{background-image: url('/assets/static/" & BannerCollection(i).retImagePath & "');}" & vbNewLine
        imgCSS = imgCSS & "#sliderTarget .banner-" & i + 1 & "{background-image: url('/assets/static/" & BannerCollection(i).imagePath & "');}" & vbNewLine
        If i = 0 Then
            firstBannerCode = firstBannerCode & "<div class=" & Chr(34) & "banner banner-" & i + 1 & " staticBanner" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
            firstBannerCode = firstBannerCode & "<a href=" & Chr(34) & BannerCollection(i).urlPath & Chr(34) & " manual_cm_re=" & Chr(34) & "MAINBANNER-_-BANNER+" & i + 1 & "-_-" & bannerTracking & Chr(34) & "></a>" & vbNewLine
            firstBannerCode = firstBannerCode & "</div>" & vbNewLine
        Else
            otherBannersCode = otherBannersCode & "<div class=" & Chr(34) & "banner banner-" & i + 1 & " staticBanner" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
            otherBannersCode = otherBannersCode & "<a href=" & Chr(34) & BannerCollection(i).urlPath & Chr(34) & " manual_cm_re=" & Chr(34) & "MAINBANNER-_-BANNER+" & i + 1 & "-_-" & bannerTracking & Chr(34) & "></a>" & vbNewLine
            otherBannersCode = otherBannersCode & "</div>" & vbNewLine
        End If
'        MsgBox (BannerCollection(i).retImagePath & vbNewLine & BannerCollection(i).imagePath & vbNewLine & BannerCollection(i).bannerTitle & vbNewLine & BannerCollection(i).urlPath)

    Next i

    CodeString = ""
    CodeString = CodeString & "<style type=" & Chr(34) & "text/css" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
    CodeString = CodeString & "/* Banners */" & vbNewLine
    CodeString = CodeString & imgCSS
    CodeString = CodeString & "/* Retina Banners */" & vbNewLine
    CodeString = CodeString & "@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {" & vbNewLine
    CodeString = CodeString & retinaCSS
    CodeString = CodeString & "}" & vbNewLine
    CodeString = CodeString & "</style>" & vbNewLine
    CodeString = CodeString & "<div id=" & Chr(34) & "sliderTarget" & Chr(34) & " class=" & Chr(34) & "slides" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
    CodeString = CodeString & firstBannerCode
    CodeString = CodeString & "</div>" & vbNewLine
    CodeString = CodeString & "<script id=" & Chr(34) & "sliderTemplate" & Chr(34) & " type=" & Chr(34) & "text/template" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
    CodeString = CodeString & otherBannersCode
    CodeString = CodeString & "</script>"

    FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & mySheet.Name & "code.txt"
    Open FilePath For Output As #2
    Print #2, CodeString
    Close #2
    MsgBox ("code.txt contains:" & CodeString)
    MsgBox (Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & mySheet.Name & "code.txt")
    Erase BannerCollection
Next mySheet

End Sub
```

and here is the `Banner` type:

```
Public Type Banner 
   imagePath As String 
   retImagePath As String 
   urlPath As String 
   bannerTitle As String 
End Type
```

Comment: What is Banner?  It isn't defined in the code you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, it's defined in a public module outside of this `Option Explicit

Public Type Banner
    imagePath As String
    retImagePath As String
    urlPath As String
    bannerTitle As String
End Type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `allCells` to a distinct range of cells correctly.

```
  Set allCells = mySheet.Range("a2", mySheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
```

Then you loop through each row in the `allCells` range.

```
  For Each r In allCells.Rows
```

But when you actually go to use *r*, it is only to use the row number.

```
  thisBanner.imagePath = Cells(r.Row, 2).Value
```

`r.Row` is a number between 1 and 1,048,576, nothing more. There is no guarantee that `Cells(r.Row, 2).Value` refers to something on **mySheet**; only that whatever worksheet it is coming from it will using whatever worksheet's row number that corresponds to `r.row`. You need to define some parentage. An `With ... End With` block within the `For ... Next` and properly annotated `.Range` and `.Cell` references should suffice.

```
Sub createCode()

    Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim bannerCount As Integer
    Dim BannerCollection() As Banner
    Dim r As Range
    Dim lastRow, lastCol
    Dim allCells As Range

    Set myWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    For Each mySheet In myWorkbook.Worksheets
        With mySheet
            'declare your vars outside the loop and zero/null then here if necessary.
            bannerCount = 0
            lastCol = .Range("a2").End(xlToRight).Column
            lastRow = .Range("a2").End(xlDown).Row
            Set allCells = .Range("a2", .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
        '    MsgBox (mySheet.Name)
        '    MsgBox ("lastRow:" & lastRow & "lastCol:" & lastCol)
            ReDim BannerCollection(allCells.Rows.Count)

            For Each r In allCells.Rows
                Dim thisBanner As Banner
                thisBanner.imagePath = ""
                thisBanner.retImagePath = ""
                thisBanner.bannerTitle = ""
                thisBanner.urlPath = ""
                bannerCount = bannerCount + 1
        '        MsgBox (bannerCount)
                thisBanner.imagePath = .Cells(r.Row, 2).Value
                thisBanner.retImagePath = .Cells(r.Row, 3).Value
                thisBanner.bannerTitle = .Cells(r.Row, 4).Value
                thisBanner.urlPath = .Cells(r.Row, 5).Value
                'MsgBox (.Cells(r.Row, 2).Value)
                'MsgBox (.Cells(r.Row, 3).Value)
                'MsgBox (.Cells(r.Row, 4).Value)
                'MsgBox (.Cells(r.Row, 5).Value)
                BannerCollection(bannerCount - 1) = thisBanner
            Next r

            Dim i As Variant
            Dim retinaCSS, imgCSS, firstBannerCode, otherBannersCode, bannerTracking As String
            retinaCSS = ""
            imgCSS = ""
            firstBannerCode = ""
            otherBannersCode = ""
            bannerTracking = ""


            For i = 0 To bannerCount - 1
                bannerTracking = BannerCollection(i).bannerTitle
                bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, " ", "+")
                bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "&", "And")
                bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "%", "PC")
                bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "!", "")
                bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "Â£", "")
                bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, ",", "")
                bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "'", "")
                bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, "#", "")
                bannerTracking = Replace(bannerTracking, ".", "")
                retinaCSS = retinaCSS & "#sliderTarget .banner-" & i + 1 & "{background-image: url('/assets/static/" & BannerCollection(i).retImagePath & "');}" & vbNewLine
                imgCSS = imgCSS & "#sliderTarget .banner-" & i + 1 & "{background-image: url('/assets/static/" & BannerCollection(i).imagePath & "');}" & vbNewLine
                If i = 0 Then
                    firstBannerCode = firstBannerCode & "<div class=" & Chr(34) & "banner banner-" & i + 1 & " staticBanner" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
                    firstBannerCode = firstBannerCode & "<a href=" & Chr(34) & BannerCollection(i).urlPath & Chr(34) & " manual_cm_re=" & Chr(34) & "MAINBANNER-_-BANNER+" & i + 1 & "-_-" & bannerTracking & Chr(34) & "></a>" & vbNewLine
                    firstBannerCode = firstBannerCode & "</div>" & vbNewLine
                Else
                    otherBannersCode = otherBannersCode & "<div class=" & Chr(34) & "banner banner-" & i + 1 & " staticBanner" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
                    otherBannersCode = otherBannersCode & "<a href=" & Chr(34) & BannerCollection(i).urlPath & Chr(34) & " manual_cm_re=" & Chr(34) & "MAINBANNER-_-BANNER+" & i + 1 & "-_-" & bannerTracking & Chr(34) & "></a>" & vbNewLine
                    otherBannersCode = otherBannersCode & "</div>" & vbNewLine
                End If
        '        MsgBox (BannerCollection(i).retImagePath & vbNewLine & BannerCollection(i).imagePath & vbNewLine & BannerCollection(i).bannerTitle & vbNewLine & BannerCollection(i).urlPath)

            Next i

            CodeString = ""
            CodeString = CodeString & "<style type=" & Chr(34) & "text/css" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
            CodeString = CodeString & "/* Banners */" & vbNewLine
            CodeString = CodeString & imgCSS
            CodeString = CodeString & "/* Retina Banners */" & vbNewLine
            CodeString = CodeString & "@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {" & vbNewLine
            CodeString = CodeString & retinaCSS
            CodeString = CodeString & "}" & vbNewLine
            CodeString = CodeString & "</style>" & vbNewLine
            CodeString = CodeString & "<div id=" & Chr(34) & "sliderTarget" & Chr(34) & " class=" & Chr(34) & "slides" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
            CodeString = CodeString & firstBannerCode
            CodeString = CodeString & "</div>" & vbNewLine
            CodeString = CodeString & "<script id=" & Chr(34) & "sliderTemplate" & Chr(34) & " type=" & Chr(34) & "text/template" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
            CodeString = CodeString & otherBannersCode
            CodeString = CodeString & "</script>"

            FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & mySheet.Name & "code.txt"
            Open FilePath For Output As #2
            Print #2, CodeString
            Close #2
            MsgBox ("code.txt contains:" & CodeString)
            MsgBox (Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & mySheet.Name & "code.txt")
            Erase BannerCollection
        End With
    Next mySheet

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great :) thanks for the swift help - i'd never even heard of 'With' - VBA definitely isn't my first language - can you tell? ;)

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing a bit of a code review (oops spent too much time on the Code Review site).  I'll post this here in addition to @Jeeped answer in case you get some value from it.

### Option Explicit

You should specify `Option Explicit` at the top of each code module.  What this does is tell the VBA compiler to check that every variable that you are trying to use has been declared (i.e. you've got `Dim blah as String`, `Public blah as String` or `Private blah as String` for each `blah` you're using).

If you attempt to use a variable which hasn't been declared, the compiler will give you a compilation error where the first problem occurs.  This helps if you mistype a variable name, otherwise the compiler will think you are talking about something new.

Adding this to the top of your code requires a couple of declarations in your code but nothing major.

### Multiple variable declaration on a single line

Don't do it.  You have the following line: `Dim retinaCSS, imgCSS, firstBannerCode, otherBannersCode, bannerTracking As String` which declares 5 variables.  The first 4 are declared as variants and the last one is a String.  Now your code may work like this but you were probably expecting all 5 to be Strings.  Other languages I believe do operate this way but VBA doesn't.

Declare them separately like:

```
Dim retinaCSS As String
Dim imgCSS As String
Dim firstBannerCode As String
Dim otherBannersCode As String
Dim bannerTracking As String
```

### Don't initialise variables unnecessarily

I see code like:

```
    CodeString = ""
    CodeString = CodeString & "<style type=" & Chr(34) & "text/css" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
```

Now the problem with this is that you're assigning the empty string value to CodeString but then you are immediately assigning something else to it in the very next line.  The risk is that you might try to use a variable before you have assigned something to it.  This isn't a risk for the string type since it implicitly assigned an empty string value when it is created.

You can safely remove the first assignment to it.  The danger could come from object references.  Say if you have a reference to a worksheet but do not assign a worksheet to the variable before you try to use it.  In any case you want to make sure that your variable has the required value before you attempt to use the value it holds.

### Use Collection instead of an array

The array code is cumbersome and inflexible.  VBA has a simple collection type which allows you to add and remove items to and from it without having to declare a fixed size.

You can also iterate through the contents using a `For Each` loop.

Here is the code I'm recommending:

```
    Dim BannerCollection As Collection
    Set BannerCollection = New Collection
    ' ...
    For Each r In allCells.Rows
        Dim thisBanner As Banner
        Set thisBanner = New Banner
        ' ...
        BannerCollection.Add thisBanner
    Next r

    ' ...
    Dim b As Banner
    For Each b In BannerCollection
        ' do something with the banner.
    Next
```

Now to do this, Banner **must** be a Class not a Type.  I think it makes life a lot easier though.

### Split a big method up into single purpose methods.

For instance I extracted a method as follows:

```
Private Function UrlEncode(ByVal text As String) As String
    text = Replace(text, " ", "+")
    text = Replace(text, "&", "And")
    text = Replace(text, "%", "PC")
    text = Replace(text, "!", "")
    text = Replace(text, "Â£", "")
    text = Replace(text, ",", "")
    text = Replace(text, "'", "")
    text = Replace(text, "#", "")
    text = Replace(text, ".", "")
    UrlEncode = text
End Function
```

Now this can be referenced like `bannerTracking = UrlEncode(b.bannerTitle)`.

Comment: Thanks for this, i'll definitely be bearing it in mind as this little piece is bound to expand further :D